# Как сделать активность главной?

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть две активности android. Одна, естественно, запускается первой, но я хочу, чтобы при запуске первой запускалась другая активность. Как сделать другую активность главной?

Comment: По формулировке вопроса не понятно, что именно Вам нужно.
Если вы хотите сделать определенную активность главной - в манифесте ставите интент-фильтр и LAUNCH(точно не помню). Если вам нужно запускать вторую активность по кнопке - то:
`Intent intent = new Intent(Ваша_активити.class, Нужная_активити.class);
startActivity(intent);` а иначе, зачем создавать лишнюю активити, из которой сразу будет вызываться еще одна активити?Помните про Бритву Оккама.

Comment: первое, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас в `Manifest.xml` две активити то вам нужно перетащить `intent-filter` с главной активити в другую активити:

заминить это

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_caling"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"/>

</application>
```

на это

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_caling"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">   
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.registration.RegistrationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```